# Babylonian Method for Solving the Square Root of a Number

Tags: python, square-root

so I have to write a program to calculate the square root of a set of range using the Babylonian method. However, I am stuck because the program I have written only gives me the square root of a single number. the range I have put in for my test is from 1, 16. But I am only getting the square root of 15.

The picture is what the program is supposed to show.[image: Program output]

```
question1 = input("Enter 'single' or 'range' to solve for a single square root or a range of values, respectively: ")
if question1 == "single":
    value1 = int(input("Please enter a positive integer above 0: "))
    if value1 <= 0:
        print("Please enter an positive integer above 0: ")
        value1 = int(input("Please enter a positive integer above 0: "))

    oValue = 1
    value2 = value1
    e = 0.0001
    while value2 - oValue > e:
        value2 = (value2 + oValue) / 2
        oValue = value1 / value2

    print(format(oValue, ".3f"))

else:
    start = int(input("Enter a positive integer value to start your range: "))
    end = int(input("Enter a positive integer value to end your range: "))
    for num in range(start, end):
        oValue = 1
        value2 = num
        e = 0.0001
        while value2 - oValue > e:
            value2 = (value2 + oValue) / 2
            oValue = num / value2

print(format(oValue, ".3f"))
```

Comment: Also, please let me know if I should format the question differently. I don't use this website much.

Comment: You need to print the result in the loop. You are printing it at the end of the loop, so you only get the last value

Answer (score 0):

Your were pretty close.  This last line needs to be indented more:

```
...
else:
    start = int(input("Enter a positive integer value to start your range: "))
    end = int(input("Enter a positive integer value to end your range: "))
    for num in range(start, end):
        oValue = 1
        value2 = num
        e = 0.0001
        while value2 - oValue > e:
            value2 = (value2 + oValue) / 2
            oValue = num / value2
        print(format(oValue, ".3f"))
```

The *print()* is part of the for-loop only if it is indented inside the loop.

When it was fully left-aligned, it was outside the for-loop, so it only ran once at the end of the script.

Hope this helps :-)